# formatting print statement for different values and function call

Tags: python, function, dictionary, printing

I'm practicing my python and trying to format the print statement of the below code for match_string so it will print in this format:

```
There are 5 numbers, 4 letters and 2 other characters.
```

I've tried to do:

```
print("There are:", + x.nums, + "numbers", +x.letters,+"letter", + x.other, +"other characters")
```

and I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'nums'
```

I also think I have an issue with the getDupes part as well but i can't figure out what, it just prints the same as.

Here's my code:

```
def match_string(words):
    nums = 0
    letter = 0
    other = 0
    for i in words :
        if i.isalpha():
            letter+=1
        elif i.isdigit():
            nums+=1
        else:
            other+=1
    return nums,letter,other


def getDupes(x):
    d = {}
    for i in x:
        if i in d:
            if d[i]:
                yield i
                d[i] = False
        else:
            d[i] = True

x = match_string(input("enter a sentence"))
c = getDupes(x)
print(x)
#print("There are:", + str(x.nums), + "numbers", +x.letters,+"letter", + x.other, +"other characters")
print("PRINT",x)
```

Comment: `return nums,letter,other` returns a tuple, not an object with `nums`, `letters`, or `other` attributes.

Comment: is there a way to convert it so it can return the way I want it to??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

funtion match_string returns a tuple hence cannot be accessed by using x.nums
instead try the below code

```
nums,letter,other = match_string(input("enter a sentence"))
print("There are:", + nums, + "numbers", + letters,+"letter", + other, +"other characters")
```

Comment: I removed the +'s from the print statement and that fixed it. thank you